# CommunicationObjectAbortedException when using Windows Azure Service Bus topic

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I got the following exception when using the Azure Service Bus. 
I built my WebJob to be ServiceBusTrigger based on the subscribed topic
Is anyone familiar with this?

> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation cannot be performed
>   because the entity has been closed or aborted. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: Internal
>   Server Error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this
>   might be caused by a premature session shutdown.
>   TrackingId:xxxxxxxxx, Timestamp:5/3/2018
>   10:02:33 PM at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.b__4(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c.b__9_3(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand(IAsyncResult
>   result, IEnumerable`1& messages) --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace --- at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.EndReceiveCommand(IAsyncResult
>   result, IEnumerable`1& messages) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult.<>c.b__12_5(ReceiveAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult a) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnEndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, IEnumerable`1& messages) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult.<>c.b__15_3(RetryReceiveAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult.TryReceiveEnd(IAsyncResult
>   r, IEnumerable`1& messages) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result, IEnumerable`1& messages) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.EndReceive(IAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceivePump.PumpAsyncResult.<>c.b__7_3(PumpAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)

Comment: Exception seems wrapper exception for some other exception. There might be error in service/function from which you are expecting output. look for inner exception or inner service exception

Comment: Thanks for the tips. However, it only happen intermittently and this is the log that I captured. Perhaps I should modify my code to unwrap the inner expcetions